# Why a "vector" type column cannot be retained in DataFrame operation

Tags: scala, dataframe

I have a dataframe featureDF as below:

[image]

I need to generate a subset fraudDF from it like below (not working):

```
val fraudDF = featureDF
      .filter($"is_fraud" === 1)
      .withColumnRenamed("is_fraud", "label")
      .select("features", "label")
```

The script seems run as expected:
[image]

I got the new dataframe below:

[image]

I am expecting columns: **features** and **label**

How should I fix it?

Thank you very much.

UPDATE:
The reason I am posting this here is because I have another function created to apply here:

```
def createBalancedDataframe(df:DataFrame, reductionCount:Int)(implicit sparkSession:SparkSession) = {

    val kMeans = new KMeans().setK(reductionCount).setMaxIter(30)
    val kMeansModel = kMeans.fit(df)

    import sparkSession.implicits._
    kMeansModel.clusterCenters.toList.map(v => (v, 0)).toDF("features", "label")
  }
```

And running

`val balancedNonFraudDF = createBalancedDataframe(nonFraudDF, fraudCount.toInt)(spark)`

will throw error saying

> Field "features" does not exist.